# Kafka creating Partitions using java API

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I had written a code to fetch twitter tweets using kafka, Its working fine but it is not working for partitions. I want to create 3 partitions for one topic .. how to pass the values to partitioner class.. Any suggestions where i am doing wrong

```
public class kafkaSpoutFetchingRealTweets {


private String consumerKey;
private String consumerSecret;
private String accessToken;
private String accessTokenSecret;
private TwitterStream twitterStream;

/**
 * @param contxt
 */
void start(final Context context) {

    /** Producer properties **/
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("metadata.broker.list",
            context.getString(Constant.BROKER_LIST));
    props.put("partitioner.class","SimplePartitioner");
    props.put("serializer.class", context.getString(Constant.SERIALIZER));
    props.put("request.required.acks",
            context.getString(Constant.REQUIRED_ACKS));
    props.put("producer.type", "async");
    // props.put("partitioner.class", context.getClass());
    ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);

    final Producer<String, String> producer = new Producer<String, String>(
            config);

    /** Twitter properties **/
    consumerKey = context.getString(Constant.CONSUMER_KEY_KEY);
    consumerSecret = context.getString(Constant.CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY);
    accessToken = context.getString(Constant.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY);
    accessTokenSecret = context.getString(Constant.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_KEY);

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
    cb.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
    cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret);
    cb.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
    cb.setIncludeEntitiesEnabled(true);

    twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

    /** Twitter listener **/
    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
        // The onStatus method is executed every time a new tweet comes
        // in.
        public void onStatus(Status status) {


            if(("en".equals(status.getLang())) && ("en".equals(status.getUser().getLang()))){

                KeyedMessage<String, String> data = new KeyedMessage<String, String>(
                        context.getString(Constant.data),
                        DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status));
                producer.send(data);
                System.out.println(DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status));

            }
        }
        }


        public void onDeletionNotice(
                StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {
        }

        public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {
        }

        public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {
        }

        public void onException(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            logger.info("Shutting down Twitter sample stream...");
            twitterStream.shutdown();
        }

        public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {
            System.out.println("stallWarning");
        }
    };


    String[] lang = { "en" };
    fq.language(lang);
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    twitterStream.sample();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Context context = new Context(args[0]);
        kafkaSpoutFetchingRealTweets tp = new kafkaSpoutFetchingRealTweets();
        tp.start(context);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Where have you read that you can create Partitions by the Java API? All that I've read is that there is no way to create Partitions by the API.

Comment: @morganw09dev... (http://fbi.wf/dir/Books/Tech/Learning%20Apache%20Kafka,%20Second%20Edition%20by%20Nishant%20Garg.pdf) ...you can find out here... I am unable to execute it

Comment: I'm not going to read through an entire pdf to help solve your problem. Looking through the Kafka Protocol, https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol, there seems to be no support for creating partitions via the Java API.

Comment: @morganw09dev..sorry I forgot to mention page Number 108,109,110 you can find out the code

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple problems.

- Your question and code don't match up. Your questions is asking about creating a topic with 3 partitions. But the code and example that you provided explains how to determine which partition the message should be sent to given that you've already created a topic with 3 partitions.
- If you're actually wanting to create a topic with 3 partitions, you need to use the command line client. A sample can be found here, http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart
- If you're actually wanting to just determine what partition you need to send data too. You'll need to provide more information about the actual problem you're encountering? Are they all going to the same partition? Then you need to look at how you're calculating the partition in your `SimplePartitioner` class that you're specifying in your config. What is in the `SimplePartitioner` class?

  ```
  props.put("partitioner.class","SimplePartitioner");
  ```

Comment: @Matthias J. Sax... oh ..It seems I confused you.. Actually I want to create a kafkaSpout which fetches twitter tweets with 3 partitions. So that in storm I can define spout Parallelism to 3. Actually I'm having high number of latency in storm spout. For the best performance tuning i had read in an article increase the parallelism of spout. So I want to create a kafkaSpout with 3 partitions So that I can fetch the tweets from those partitions from storm.

Comment: What? I'm not Matthias J. Sax?? Yes, you are confusing me.

Comment: I got it ... what it means... 1. Create the above kafkaSpout 2. From command line create the topic name with partitions we need 3. Execute the kafkaSpout jar.